# How to use the Carpenter from the Forestry mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I'm trying to craft a small circuit board with a carpenter. I've put a redstone engine next to it like this:

[image: setup]

And I have added the needed ingredients and recipe like this:

[image: gui]

But nothing is happening. I can't take out the crafted item that is shown. If I take out one of the ingredients, the GUI will display a warning that there is a missing ingredient. I tried powering the carpenter with a switch, but that didn't help either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The carpenter in your screenshot *is* working, but very, very slowly. A Redstone Engine is woefully underpowered for most Forestry machines, and for some machines doesn't even satisfy the minimum input requirements.

For the Carpenter you should use at least one Stirling Engine, though two will make it go at a more satisfying speed. For other machines (such as the Thermionic Fabricator) I've found that Combustion Engines or IC2-powered Electrical Engines give satisfying results. I have a battery of four Electricals in my factory basement right now that are overkill for most of my mid-game Buildcraft and Forestry needs.

Comment: You were right, I attached a stirling engine and it did the job fairly quickly. Thanks!

Comment: Redstone engines were meant for powering buildcraft first extracting pipes (wooden) and buildcraft pumps (though not at full speed until green), they are not practical for anything else as they are worse than a clockwork engine. If you are just starting out, use either the clockwork engine (forestry only) or if you have buildcraft, use the sterling engine. If you have railcraft also, go with the tier 1 steam engine (hobbyist's). It is basically a steam generator + boiler in one and is good for early game power for single blocks (like carpenter and railcraft's rolling machine).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a steam engine or higher . You can still run it on Redstone engines but you will nead at least 32 I gave found that the minimal amount.